# how can I search json in mysql via medoo library?

Tags: php, mysql, json, medoo

I have a column in a mysql DB with this json content:

```
{"section2":"303","section1":"302","section0":"301"}
```

I use Medoo library. How can I search section1, section2, section3 in DB?

```
$database->select('Article', "*",[
                            "AND" => [
                            "section" => ?
                            ]
                       ])

                   )
```

Comment: it seems that medoo doesn't support json yet.

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just do this?

```
$database->select('Article', "*",[
    'section' => json_encode([
                  'section0' => 301,
                  'section1' => 302,
                  'section2' => 303
                 ])
]);
```

Unless of course, your trying to check for only one section. Then, no, I dont see how its possible using just sql.

Answer (score 0):

Just search the string using like condition matching the JSON format value:

```
$database->select('Article', '*', [
    "section[~]" => [
        '"section1":"302"',
        '"section2":"303"',
        '"section3":"304"'
    ]
]);
```